# PHP POST request to AWS gateway without curl

Tags: php, api, http, request, stream

Im trying to make a http post request to a aws API Gateway without the uses of any php library's. I have tested this on windows environment and it works, when I move it over to my Linux embedded device Im getting a "failed to open stream: Unable to find the socket transport "ssl".

Looking at other post I have enabled "extension=php_openssl.dll" in php.ini

Being new to php, and needing it to be pure php, is this the best way to go about this?

The Code:

```
$w = stream_get_wrappers();
echo 'openssl: ',  extension_loaded  ('openssl') ? 'yes':'no', "\n";
echo 'http wrapper: ', in_array('http', $w) ? 'yes':'no', "\n";
echo 'https wrapper: ', in_array('https', $w) ? 'yes':'no', "\n";
echo 'wrappers: ', var_dump($w);

//request password and next password.
$opts = array(
    'http' => array(
        'method' => 'GET',
        'header' => "Content-Type: application/json\r\n".
                    "x-api-key: **********************\r\n",
    )
);
$context  = stream_context_create($opts);
//this @ suppress the warning about a bad http call
$passwords = file_get_contents($RequestPassURL , false, $context);
var_dump($passwords);
```

The Output:

```
openssl: no
http wrapper: yes
https wrapper: no
wrappers: array(6) {
  [0]=>
  string(3) "php"
  [1]=>
  string(4) "file"
  [2]=>
  string(4) "glob"
  [3]=>
  string(4) "data"
  [4]=>
  string(4) "http"
  [5]=>
  string(3) "ftp"
}

Warning: file_get_contents(http://AWSURL): failed to open stream: Unable to find the socket transport "ssl" - did you forget to enable it when you configured PHP? in /home/root/changPass on line 71
bool(false)
```

Comment: where did you enable the extension=php_openssl.dll? in linux or in win ?

Comment: It was enabled on the Linux device.

Comment: Hello @KevinLucas, your question can be splitted into three separate questions, as you clearly pointed out. In this respect, you should put more focus onto your question: assume that three people separately spend effort to reply each one to one of the points of your list. Who would you award as "Accepted Answer"?